# how to use gulp to import a web template into a vue application

Tags: vue.js, gulp

I am brand new to VueJS.  I have a brand new project that I want to ingest some global SCSS and javascript into the project through gulp/webpack, so it'll be properly set to start building stuff.  As I figure this out.

I have a new project that has the standard folders:

```
.
./dist
./dist/css
./dist/js
./node_modules
./public
./.git
./src
./src/components
./src/assets
```

Right now it displays the default Vue components that come along with a new project.

I have a new template product that has two options to install them.
The File structure for the template solution is:

```
template/
├── dist/             // generated html / css / js files
├── gulpfile.js       // gulp settings
├── package.json      // npm package installed
└── src/
    ├── html/         // html source files
    ├── img/          // image source files
    ├── js/           // javascript source files
    └── scss/         // studio scss files
```

First one is the global connectors:

```
<!-- Core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/vendor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 
<!-- Core JS -->
<script src="assets/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

now I can put that into the main index.html, but the guidance on the template states:

```
cd /your-path-url/template_html/
npm install 
gulp
 
// generate plugins command
gulp plugins
```

The location of the project is: `~/Projects/web1/`
The location of the template is: `~/templates/HUD/`

How do I tell one that the other is there, and ingest the HUD template into the web1 project, so I can use the SCSS and JS Involved?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have you chosen Gulp for a new project?

Comment: I didn't.  the template instructions did.

Comment: Can you share a link to those instructions?

Comment: there is a lot of missing info for an outsider to answer this question. Also I suggest to ditch Gulp since it really isnt necessary in most cases; you can always solve it with a plain javascript file and an `npm run myscriptname`